# Noob at MonoDroid, Emulator is not running my app, what am I missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I am a C# developer, but completely new to MonoDroid and Android development in general. I just downloaded MonoDroid a few minutes ago, fired up VS 2010, and followed the directions here (http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/hello_world) to create the HelloWorld application. Should be pretty simple, right? Everything compiles, and I ran the app in non-debug mode as instructed. The emulator starts up, but... the app doesn't start. And when I look in the Apps directory, I don't see anything that says HelloWorld or looks like my app.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After you start the emulator, does it then show up in the device list?  If so, when you select it, does it say stuff like "Packaging your Application", "Deploying your Application", etc?  Is there any reported error?

Comment: It is NOT showing up in my devices list. And yet I do see the emulator running on the screen. It's at the opening screen where you need to slide to unlock it.

Comment: ALso, when I close the emulator, VS shows an error, sort of. It says Error: Cancelled
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant "does it show up as a WINDOWS device"... so yes, it shows up in the "Select a Device" dialog as a running device.

Comment: What happens when you choose it in the "Select a Device" dialog?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, after the emulator shows as selected (like you said you should be on the **slide to unlock screen**), click <kbd>OK</kbd> again on the **Select Device/Start** Emulator screen. Then in the bottom left corner of Visual Studios 2010 you will see it deploying and packaging your application. If this is the first time you've done this it will need to install some onetime programs, mono shared runtime, etc.

It in theory should work after that.